# Is there a Latin equivalent to ἐπίκοινος?

Tags: greek, example-request, gender, grammarians, terminology

The Ancient Greek grammatical tradition, going back to Dionysius Thrax (or maybe farther), distinguishes five types of nouns: masculine, feminine, neuter, common, and epicene (ἐπίκοινος). Four of these names caught on in their Latin forms, spreading to other languages mostly via Latin, but the fifth always seems to appear as a Greek loanword.

Did any grammarians use a Latin equivalent? Or is it always borrowed from Greek?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Priscian would probably have called it *genus promiscuum* or *genus epicoenum*:

[image]

Diomedes adds:

“Latini promiscuum vel subcommune vocant”